# Groupby and grep value in order to fil one column in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hello I have a df such as

```
COL1 COL2 COL3
G1   pen1 NA
G1   OK   NA
G1   BGA  NA
G2   OK   ALREADY
G2   KI   ALREADY
G2   LO   ALREADY
G3   pen1 NA
G3   LO   NA
G3   L09  NA
```

and I would like to add 'CHECK' in `COL3` within each `COL1` that have any `COL2 == pen1`

```
COL1 COL2 COL3
G1   pen1 CHECK
G1   OK   CHECK
G1   BGA  CHECK
G2   OK   ALREADY
G2   KI   ALREADY
G2   LO   ALREADY
G3   pen1 CHECK
G3   LO   CHECK
G3   L09  CHECK
```

does someone have an idea using dplyr ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `if`/`else` condition.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(COL1) %>%
  mutate(COL3 = if(any(COL2 == 'pen1')) 'CHECK' else COL3)

#  COL1  COL2  COL3   
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>  
#1 G1    pen1  CHECK  
#2 G1    OK    CHECK  
#3 G1    BGA   CHECK  
#4 G2    OK    ALREADY
#5 G2    KI    ALREADY
#6 G2    LO    ALREADY
#7 G3    pen1  CHECK  
#8 G3    LO    CHECK  
#9 G3    L09   CHECK
```

Comment: Sorry for that but I edited the post, in fact I need to keep the value already present in the COL3, and not add NA in COL1 where there is no 'pen1' value in COL2.

Comment: In `else` use `COL3` then instead of `NA`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more readable version.

```
df %>% group_by(COL1) %>% mutate(COL3 = replace(COL3, any(COL2 == "pen1"), "CHECK"))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   COL1 [3]
  COL1  COL2  COL3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 G1    pen1  CHECK  
2 G1    OK    CHECK  
3 G1    BGA   CHECK  
4 G2    OK    ALREADY
5 G2    KI    ALREADY
6 G2    LO    ALREADY
7 G3    pen1  CHECK  
8 G3    LO    CHECK  
9 G3    L09   CHECK
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(COL1) %>% mutate(COL3 = case_when(any(COL2 == 'pen1') ~ 'CHECK', TRUE ~ COL3))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   COL1 [3]
  COL1  COL2  COL3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 G1    pen1  CHECK  
2 G1    OK    CHECK  
3 G1    BGA   CHECK  
4 G2    OK    ALREADY
5 G2    KI    ALREADY
6 G2    LO    ALREADY
7 G3    pen1  CHECK  
8 G3    LO    CHECK  
9 G3    L09   CHECK
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  COL1  COL2  COL3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 G1    pen1  NA     
2 G1    OK    NA     
3 G1    BGA   NA     
4 G2    OK    ALREADY
5 G2    KI    ALREADY
6 G2    LO    ALREADY
7 G3    pen1  NA     
8 G3    LO    NA     
9 G3    L09   NA
```

Comment: Sorry for that but I edited the post, in fact I need to keep the value already present in the COL3, and not add NA in COL1 where there is no 'pen1' value in COL2.

Comment: @chippycentra, have edited my answer, please check if that works.